# Creating new master and dev branches from existing repository

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have an existing git repo which has 4 branches which were not structured properly. Me and one more developer work on only one branch and we keep on updating and merging into that same branch. We use the same branch in staging and production server for both testing and deploying! I know its not a good practice, so I want to follow this [post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) from now on. Presently my branch on which I am working is not stable, the stable version is some commits behind. How should I start about having a stable master branch and dev branches.

Can I completely start afresh from a stable old commit(forgeting all the other old branches) and build all the new branches?
Shall I checkout my new stable master branch from an old commit? From that previous commit shall I go about building my new dev branch also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tricky to give advice on this without knowing the particulars of your project.

But would it be a feasible option to finish up what you've got going on in the branches you want to get rid of (make them stable) and then merging them into master? If so, then you could do that, delete the old branches that you don't want and start anew with your new branching model.

Alternatively, maybe you could start by merging the unwanted branches together in a new branch, stabilise that, merge it into master and make it your main "develop branch?"

Assuming that you'd like to keep all the changes made in the 4 unstable branches, the "correct approach" would depend on if – and how long – you're willing to destabilise master, amongst other things; if it's sane to merge these branches together, etc.

Also, I think the "appropriate solution" depends largely on your current and desired workflow.

Comment: we have been working on single branch from almost two months and presently it is stable at a old commit. Can I merge that old commit to the old master branch and make it the new master branch? And from that I will start a new dev branch and delete the rest of the branches which I am not gonna use anymore.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to merge the branch you've been working on for the past few months up until a specified commit, by using going to the master branch (`git checkout master`) and doing `git merge <old_commit_id>`.

Please note that I am not sure if I understand exactly what you want to do, so be careful and read the git manuals to make sure that you really understand these commands before you use them (do `git help merge` and read it thoroughly).